# method post javascript jquery

Tags: javascript

i have a problem with my javascript/jquery code . I try to make a form with post method only with javascript/jquery . the problem with my form is  when you use the submit button  i dont kwow how i can get the post

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function () {
    console.log('Click détecté ');
  var form = document.createElement('form');
            form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
            //form.setAttribute('action', '');
            document.body.appendChild(form);
            
            
            let monSelect = document.createElement('select');
             let monOption = document.createElement('option');
                    monOption.setAttribute('value', 1);
                    monOption.innerText = 'choice1';
                    monSelect.appendChild(monOption);
                let monOption2 = document.createElement('option');
                    monOption2.setAttribute('value', 2);
                    monOption2.innerText = 'choice2';
                    monSelect.appendChild(monOption2);
           form.appendChild(monSelect);
            let input = document.createElement('input')
            input.setAttribute('type', "submit");
            input.setAttribute('value', "envoyer");
            input.setAttribute('name', "typecolonne");
            form.appendChild(input);
            
        }
        
    );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Quelques langages</title>
</head>

<body>
    <button id="test">Ajouter un block</button>

    <script src="test.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your code doesn't even use jquery.

Comment: can you elaborate on "i dont kwow how i can get the post" ? do you mean you don't know how to send a POST request?

Comment: yes , i dont know how to send a POST request